# mac hard-drive keeps getting drained until the next reboot

Tags: macos, catalina

ever since I upgraded my Mac to El Capitan ( now I'm with Catalina ) - my hard drive is acting strange.

After a reboot I start with having almost 14GB of free space, and somehow a long the way it's getting lowered as the time goes by .... you can literally see it with watch du -h over time ...

Now I have 391Mi free space, and after a reboot it goes by to 13/14GB ... and then it goes again.

The behavior sometimes feels like that applications I open - take memory/disk, and when i close them - i'm not getting the memory back ...

Activity monitor - doesn't do much for me ...

I'm not sure why this is happening, and I wanted to request suggestions / tools - on how to start debugging it ....

### Edit

I know this post was considered "already answered"
but this is no a matter of "where my disk space go?" to clean it up.
It's something else, example:

```
08:55:13 $ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5   234Gi   10Gi  2.2Gi    82%  484313 2448641047    0%   /

11:47:30 $ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5   234Gi   10Gi  1.1Gi    91%  484313 2448641047    0%   /

12:57:27 $ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5   234Gi   10Gi  115Mi    99%  484313 2448641047    0%   /

12:57:28 $ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5   234Gi   10Gi   84Mi   100%  484313 2448641047    0%   /
                              ^^^
                             CRAZY
```

Where, in 3 hours 1G go ?! .... the Mac was idle ... I wasn't near it ..
After working (using Outlook/iTerm etc .. ) - after 1 hour - 100MB !?
something crazy is going on ..

Comment: 14GB is critically low free space. Minimum 10% free on a large drive, considerably more on a small drive.

Comment: yeah, but what can I do .. the disk is small ...

Comment: Saw this post in reopen queue. Re you edit, there are two ways I know which can find disk space usage: **1** Activity monitor > disk tab. something that writes 10 GB so fast would definitely show up if you sort the table. **2** Use the answers in the question @Tetsujin linked and see _where_ the files are. Let me know by @ pinging me after adding the results to the post. It's also worth testing if this happens in the safe mode too. https://support.apple.com/HT201262

Comment: Time Machine local backups or bird could easily account for 14GB - amongst the reasons your drive is critically over-full.

Comment: @anki Google Chrome: 9GB (?!) ...

Comment: I assume this info is from Activity Monitor, disk tab. So is Chrome downloading something ? Or is any of its extensions corrupt?

Comment: no, usual ... i'm working with it all the time. found another one: `kernel_task` 72GB - what's that about ? I can't close it

Comment: What are you actually trying to do now?? You can't 'close' kernel-task, it's the top level process which is in charge of every other process on your Mac. You need to clear some space on your drive. That is the only 'fix'. [Or get a bigger drive]

Comment: @Tetsujin I know that, but it's impossible to always clear and something in the Mac is "eat"ing the space all the time ... how in 3 or 4 hours I'm left with 84M ? after reboot I start from scratch - until the space run out - I reboot again, but it's crazy working like that

Comment: I'm not sure how many different ways I can say this… You *must* leave the drive room to breathe. You're choking it. It will come back eventually to bite hard, because something will fail, permanently. Make some space on the drive. **There is no other solution**. 14GB free space, as you can see, is nowhere near enough. On a tiny drive like that, you should be thinking more like 30 to 50GB free space. Then it will stop complaining at you & will last longer. When it's nearly full you are constantly overwriting the same few areas of the drive, which will eventually lead to early failure.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the assistance, but I refuse to believe that in 2020 I need to have 50GB free space for a system to work properly.

Comment: i stopped using Chrome ... using Brave now ... disk seems to be the same across all day, the disk doesn't get drained.. no nothing ... :/